# Android Google drive api creating file offline results in 2 files created

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

So I'm aware of the limitations of the drive API and how it caches locally, and how it's never garantueed to be synced with the server.

I'm trying to create a simple file but what's happening is when I create the file offline, and go online, it results in two identical files on the sever. I get this behavior from this code, which is almost identical to the sample code:

```
    final Task<DriveFolder> rootFolderTask = mDriveResourceClient.getRootFolder();
    final Task<DriveContents> contentsTask = mDriveResourceClient.createContents();
    Tasks.whenAll(rootFolderTask, contentsTask)
            .continueWithTask(new Continuation<Void, Task<DriveFile>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<DriveFile> then(@NonNull Task<Void> task) throws Exception {
                    DriveFolder folder = rootFolderTask.getResult();
                    DriveContents contents = contentsTask.getResult();

                    OutputStream outputStream = contents.getOutputStream();
                    try {
                        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
                        writer.write("Hello World");
                        writer.close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {}

                    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                            .setTitle("Hello_World.txt")
                            .setMimeType("text/plain")
                            .setStarred(true)
                            .build();

                    return mDriveResourceClient.createFile(folder, changeSet, contents);
                }
            })
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DriveFile>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DriveFile driveFile) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "File write complete");
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "File write failed");
                }
            });
```

This code is nearly identical to [Creating files in the GDAA guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file).

What happens is:

- Turn on airplane mode (go offline)
- Open the app, run the code
- The code succeeds (file is cached locally)
- Exit the app
- Turn off airplane mode (go online)

Now the result is, after 10 or so seconds the file appears on the server in google drive, and a few seconds later an identical file appears. So the result is two identical files being created.

Why does this happen? And how can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: I would suggest creating files when you're actually online. You just mentioned the errors that happens when you're offline, why push through?

Comment: Well I figured since the API does automatic local caching it would be fine. This would be helpful in my application and save some error catching. I wonder if it's a bug in the API?